# Given a string containing uppercase alphabets (A-Z), compress the string using Run Length encoding

Tags: python, string, run-length-encoding

Given a string containing uppercase alphabets (A-Z), compress the string using Run Length encoding. Repetition of character has to be replaced by storing the length of that run.

I tried the following codes

```
#Code 1: Tried on my own


    def encode(message):
        list1=[]
        for i in range (0,len(message)):
            count = 1
            while(i < len(message)-1 and message[i]==message[i+1]):
                count+=1
                i+=1
                list1=str(count)+message[i]
                return list1
    encoded_message=encode("ABBBBCCCCCCCCAB")
    print(encoded_message)



Input:AAAABBBBCCCCCCCC  
Expected Output: 4A4B8C



#code 2:I tried this by looking at another code based on run-length encoding

    def encode(message):
        list1=[]
        count=1
        for i in range (1,len(message)):
            if(message[i]==message[i-1]):
                count+=1
            else:
                list1.append((count,list1[i-1]))
                count=1
            if i == len(messege) - 1 :
                list1.append((count , data[i]))
        return list1

    encoded_message=encode("ABBBBCCCCCCCCAB")
    print(encoded_message)
```

Input:AAAABBBBCCCCCCCC
Expected Output: 4A4B8C

The first code gives output as 2B

Comment: The first `encode()` function contains a `return` statement in the inner while loop, which causes the function to exit immediately.  That loop will only run once.

Answer (score 0):

```py
def encode(message):
    pairs = []
    for char in message:
        if len(pairs) > 0:
            if pairs[-1][0] == char:
                pairs[-1] = (char, pairs[-1][1] + 1)
            else:
                pairs.append((char, 1))
        else:
            pairs.append((char, 1))
    strings = []
    for letter, count in pairs:
        strings.append(f"{count}{letter.upper()}")
    return "".join(strings)


print(encode("ABBBBCCCCCCCCAB"))
print(encode("AAAABBBBCCCCCCCC"))
```

This outputs:

```py
1A4B8C1A1B
4A4B8C
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a very good use for the `groupby` function from itertools:

```
from itertools import groupby

message = 'AAAABBBBCCCCCCCC'

''.join('{}{}'.format(len(list(g)), c) for c, g in groupby(message))
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code #2 method I have tweaked it to give out the output as you have in Expected Output: 4A4B8C

basically, your returning a tuple in a list so you needed to make it a string instead and add to it your also using data but have no data variable and your trying to find the content of the message, not your list so the code would be

```
def encode2(message):
        encoded_return_message = ""
        count=1
        for i in range (1,len(message)):
            if(message[i]==message[i-1]):
                count+=1
            else:
                encoded_return_message += (f'{count}{message[i-1]}')
                count=1
            if i == len(message) - 1 :
                encoded_return_message +=(f'{count}{message[i]}')
        return encoded_return_message

encoded_message=encode2("ABBBBCCCCCCCCAB")
print(str(encoded_message))
```

I also did a demo on Repl.it

https://repl.it/repls/RowdyFloralwhiteBlockchain

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would do that task using `re` module following way:

```
import re
text = 'AAAABBBBCCCCCCCC'
def sub_function(m):
    span = m.span()
    return f"{span[1]-span[0]}"+m.groups()[0]
out = re.sub(r'(\w)(\1*)',sub_function,text)
print(out)
```

Output:

```
4A4B8C
```

Explanation: pattern in `re.sub` is looking for letter followed by `0` or more occurences of same letter, than every such substring is feed to `sub_function` which calculate overall length of substring and return that value concatenated with first letter (which is same as all others) of substring. Note that I used so-called f-string in my code which is not available in older versions (I tested my code in `Python 3.6.7`), if you have to use older version you need to use other string formatting method. Note also that my code as is would replace single letter with digit `1` plus that letter for example input `ABC` would result in `1A1B1C`, if you wish to retain single letters without adding `1` then change 1st argument of `re.sub` from `r'(\w1)(\1*)'` to `r'(\w1)(\1+)'`

Though maybe now I am the guy with hammer seeing nails everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

```
def encode(message):
    count=0
    characters=''
    previous_char=message[0]
    result='' 
    length=len(message)
    i=0
    while(i!=length):
       character=message[i]
       if previous_char==character:
          count=count+1
       else:
          result=result+str(count)+previous_char
          count=1
       previous_char=character
       i=i+1
    return result+str(count)+str(previous_char)
encoded_messsage=encode("ABBBBCCCCCCCCAB")
print(encoded_message)
```

Input is:ABBBBCCCCCCCCAB

output is:1A4B8C1A1B

Answer (score 0):

```
def encodeString(s):
  encoded = ""
  ctr = 1
  for i in range(len(s)-1):
    if s[i]==s[i+1]:
      ctr += 1
      i += 1 
    else:
      encoded = encoded + str(ctr) + s[i]
      i += 1
      ctr = 1
    #print(encoded)
  
  encoded = encoded + str(ctr) + s[i]
  #print(encoded)
  return encoded
```

Input :"AAAAABBCCDDAB"
Output: 5A2B2C4D1A1B

Answer (score 0):

```
def encode(message):
    list1=[]
    count=1
    for i in range (1,len(message)):
        if(message[i].upper()==message[i-1].upper()):
            count+=1
        else:
            list1.append(f"{count}{message[i-1].upper()}")
            count=1
        if i == len(message) - 1 :
            list1.append(f"{count}{message[i].upper()}")
    return "".join(list1)

encoded_message=encode("ABBBBCCCCCCCCAB")
print(encoded_message)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).